# Set up several WiFi AP to broadcast one network

Tags: wireless-networking, repeater

Given that one needs to cover a large area with a WiFi connection, and wants to use three different wireless access points to do it, is it possible to set them up in such way, so that they all broadcast access to a single WiFi network (one name, one password, and the device, traveling back and forth from one unit coverage to another "wouldn't notices" the difference)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple access points for the same SSID?](http://superuser.com/questions/122441/multiple-access-points-for-the-same-ssid)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Grab a couple used WRT54G's http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linksys_WRT54G_series and load them up with DD-WRT and configure for a repeater bridge http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Repeater_Bridge

though, you "would notice" since the AP names will be different, but, they all go back to a single uplink. With auto-connect you shouldn't notice much.

edit -

you *could* make the name the same, but from the DD-WRT site:

> Wireless Network Name(SSID) : Different from Primary Router
>   [NOTE] - You CAN try using the same SSID but it usually will not work properly. Many have had random disconnects and/or no connection if the SSID's are the same. If using the same ssid doesn't work for you, use a different ssid from the primary router

Comment: 802.11 was designed from the start to support multiple APs all broadcasting the same SSID, to form a roaming network. What kind of network backhaul (i.e. wired or wireless Ethernet) you use doesn't matter. See http://superuser.com/questions/122441/multiple-access-points-for-the-same-ssid

Answer (score 0):

For the most part yes. Use the same channel, SSID and password and your users shouldn't notice an issue. Now if someone is say in a video conference they might be dropped at the switch off, but atleast at my work this is how we did it.