# How do I set up multiple access points with a Packetfront DRG700 broadband modem?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, modem, dhcp

I have a Packetfront DRG700 broadband modem (fiberoptic), which also has a wireless DHCP server built-in. In addition I have a D-Link DIR-615 router which is connected by cable to the modem. I want both units to be wireless access points for the same local network.

I've tried disabling the DHCP server on the D-Link and naming both units with the same SSID and passphrase, but that didn't work because whenever I'm wirelessly connected to the D-Link, I get an IP address from my broadband provider and not from the DHCP server on my modem; i.e. I'm no longer connected to my local network.

I'm told by my provider that the reason is because the DHCP server on the DRG700 only works wireless, while the LAN ports are given IPs from outside the house. (I would use one of these ports for my broadband TV decoder.)

I don't suppose there is any way to get this to work without having to buy an extra router?

Comment: Can you change the configuration of the ports on the DRG700?

Comment: I don't think so, no. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Still looking for an answer... anyone?

Answer (score 0):

from what i am aware of that packetfront drg700 doesn't have a wifi access point built in? anyway i guess yours does. moving on past why you would need 2 wireless ap's sitting right next to each other on the same ssid:

what i would do if i were you is install dd-wrt firmware on your dir-615 and set it up as a repeater in bridged mode, then create a virtual interface to bridge your existing connection to and name it something like yourssid2 so you know which one you are connecting to. it's not a good idea to have 2 ap's running on the same ssid, it confuses the clients. also since you've now just turned your boring soho router into an awesome wireless repeater you can take this thing and put it anywhere you can pick up a wireless signal from your drg700 and use it to extend the range of your wifi network to your back yard or something without having to run 100 feet of cat5 cable.

also if you don't want to install dd-wrt just use the dir-615 factory firmware: do a full factory reset because it sounds like you've screwed up your settings (this is usually done by holding reset for 30 seconds or something similar) then go change the ssid on the dir-615 to something OTHER than the ssid of your drg700's wireless ssid. check to be sure dhcp is on, check to be sure the dhcp addresses your devices are giving are NOT in the same range (you won't want to have 192.168.1.101 assigned to two devices on your network at once this is no good either!)

whatever you do, once you're done be sure to set up some wpa or something like that on both ap's so someone doesn't get on your network and screw all your settings up once you have them working.

Comment: I never said the ap's would be sitting right next to each other. I've already ran the length I need of cat5 cable to avoid using wireless bandwidth to extend the network.

What you're suggesting will either (dd-wrt) use wireless bandwidth or (factory firmware) give me two separate networks, and that's not what I need.

As to having two APs with the same SSID, according to the accepted answer in [this post](http://superuser.com/questions/122441/multiple-access-points-for-the-same-ssid) that's the right way to do it.