# Multiple Access Points - Same SSID (Complicated Setup)

Tags: networking, wireless-access-point, bridge-router

My current network utilizes WPA2-Enterprise as its authentication method. I am trying to extend my network further, but most wireless routers that I have found don't support repeating a WPA2-Enterprise signal. So, therefore, I purchased an ASUS EA-N66 to use as my receiver. And, that has worked pretty successfully so far with just a router connected to it. However, I now want to add another AP *using the same SSID and same authentication server* where it currently lists as `(Additional AP)`. My question is how does the `Additonal AP` now differentiate which network to connect to, the `Wireless AP/Router` vs `Additional AP`? My concern is that it will form a loop and then never connect to anything.

My (target/current) network topography looks like this:

```
                  RADIUS Server
                       ^
                       |
                       |
Internet  --> Wireless AP/Router <-(WPA-2 Enterprise)-> EA-N66 ----> Router
                                                                        |
                                                                        |
                                                                        |
                                                                 (Additional AP)
```

Is there something I should be doing specifically to mitigate this problem? Or is there any existing technology that already allows it to avoid this problem?

Previous Research:
I have referred to "[How can I get the same SSID for multiple access points?](https://superuser.com/questions/122441/how-can-i-get-the-same-ssid-for-multiple-access-points)" however it does not exactly fit into my problem.