# Wireless range extender

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wrt54g, wireless-extender

I have a LinkSys WRT54G wifi router setup as an a AP, connected to me LAN in router mode (as I have an ADSL router for internet connection).
Wifi setup with WPA2 with a password and a MAC list.
I tried adding a TP-Link TL-WA730RE as a range extender.
Connected the TP to the LAN via cable and run through the quick setup. Added the TP MAC address to the WRT Mac address list. Everything looks fine, I can also see the TP web interface.
BUT the range extender function does not work.
I can't see the TP connect to the WRT and the Range extender led on the TP does not light.
Scaned the web for solutions - found nothinkg except making sure both units runs G mode.

Any ideas on what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Range extender mode is only for when you want your second AP to connect to the first AP wirelessly.  Since you have the ability to connect the two via an Ethernet cable, you should use that as your backhaul between the two instead of using wireless.  It sounds like you've accidentally set up two separate backhauls between the two devices, which may have created a network loop (depending on how smart or dumb the devices are).

So, turn off range extender mode, and put it in plain AP mode, with the same SSID, security type, and password as your main AP.  For more information, see
"[How can I get the same SSID for multiple access points?](https://superuser.com/questions/122441/how-can-i-get-the-same-ssid-for-multiple-access-points/122508#122508)"

Comment: I can connect the 2nd unit to the wire LAN only for setup purposes. I want to put the extender where I don't have wire access, so I do need the extender functionality