# Is it possible to change WiFi Access Point at a higher connection threshold

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

The following answer answers nicely how to use multiple APs for a single wireless network

[How can I get the same SSID for multiple access points?](https://superuser.com/questions/122441/how-can-i-get-the-same-ssid-for-multiple-access-points/122508#122508)

The answer states that your device will change to a better AP if the connection drops below a certain level and a better AP is available. But, as pointed out in the comments, computers tend only to change AP when the connection to the current AP is *extremely* low. Basically, it hangs on too long.

Is there anyway to increase the threshould that your computer swaps APs?

I finally have good coverage in all points of my house by using 4 APs but still have connection issues as my computer stays connected to a far-away AP.

Answer (score 4):

The setting you're looking for is called `Roaming Aggressiveness`, or at least that's what Intel calls it.

AP roaming isn't standardized; you're really at the mercy of your WiFi drivers when it comes to this. Typically, WiFi roaming is up to the client side implementation. (Cisco does have some fancy proprietary implementations of WiFi roaming that involve AP side settings, but you probably won't run in to that.)

You can find the setting on Intel WiFi devices by the following [these instructions for Windows](http://www.intel.com/support/wireless/wlan/sb/CS-025393.htm):

> To access the advanced Wi-Fi adapter settings, complete the following
>   steps.
>
> - Right-click the My Computer icon on the desktop or from the Start
>     menu.
> - Click Manage.
> - Click Device Manager.
> - Click the + sign to expand
>     the Network Adapters entry.
> - Right-click the wireless adapter and click
>     Properties.
> - Click the Advanced tab to configure the advanced settings.

Then select the Roaming Aggressiveness property and tweak accordingly.

As for other vendors, check the documentation.

Comment: Yep, on Windows, it's going to be one of your Wi-Fi driver's advanced properties, if it's something you can tweak.

Comment: Ah, I have a bad habit of assuming Windows. Edited answer. What's the lay of the land when it comes to Linux?

Comment: Great - thanks @Tanner.
Does anyone know what the story is with this setting & iOS devices?