# Can I use same SSID for dlink modem router and AirPort Time Capsule?

Tags: wireless-networking, ssid, airport-extreme

My ADSL modem/router is DLink (AC1200 dual band).  I recently purchased a Mac and an Airport Time Capsule.  The AirPort is connected via Ethernet cable to the DLink modem/router to increase range of wireless at the back of my house.

The Airport has its own SSID.  Am I able to use the SSID the same for both the DLink and Airport so that when devices connect they only need to know one SSID? The type of devices connecting include iPhones, MacBook, iMac, iPad and a Windows laptop.

At the moment I have 3 SSID's, one for each of the following:

1. DLink 2.4 GHz
2. DLink 5 GHz
3. AirPort

The iMac is closest to the DLink so uses the 2.4 GHz DLink SSID.   However that means I can't see the Airport TimeCapsule from the iMac because it is on a different WiFi network. I need to have the iMac connected to the Airport SSID to access resources it provides.

I'm not very technical. I would appreciate advice on whether it is possible to share a single SSID across both routers.  I would also appreciate instructions on what config changes I need to make.

Thanks in advance,
Tim.

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple access points share the same SSID (and the same credentials) and smart clients will automatically select the one with the strongest signal and roam seamlessly from one to another.  See the SuperUser question: [How can I get the same SSID for multiple access points?](https://superuser.com/questions/122441/how-can-i-get-the-same-ssid-for-multiple-access-points) for more details.

If you have connected the Airport Time Capsule to the WLAN router,  you should be able to access it when connected to the router.  Maybe you have to configure the router to forward traffic from WLAN to the LAN.

Especially having different SSIDs on 2.4 and 5 GHz on the same router seem to make no sense to me unless you have the special need to separate them.

Answer (score 0):

If the AirPort Time Capsule is already connected to the D-Link router via an Ethernet cable, then you should disable NAT on the AirPort Time Capsule, so that it's just bridging between Ethernet and Wi-Fi. Once you do that, your Mac will be able to see the Time Capsule's services even when your Mac is connected to your D-Link device.