# How to passively connect to a wireless network while actively connecting to another?

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, virtual-wifi

I want to connect to two Wi-Fi networks at the same time.
The first Wi-Fi needs to think I'm connected to it because it activates (power) another Wi-Fi that I will use actively.

If I don't connect to the first Wi-Fi it will shut down after 2 minutes of inactivity and will shut down the second Wi-Fi with it.

How can I simulate a connection to the first Wi-Fi while using another?

OS: MacOS Sierra
Wifi Key: USB Realtek Wi-Fi 802.11b/g/n/a/ac 8814AU

Comment: Many WLAN devices allow several network interfaces as STA (station/client), so you can be connected to multiple networks (and even use them actively). You didn't tell us your OS, or what hardware you have ...

Comment: I want to get this working on a Mac. I can buy a wireless USB key if needed.

Comment: @boulabiar Well if you have a second wifi interface, things should be pretty straight forward. Just connect to the desired AP, with the interface that you want. If you only have one interface, then no. Check [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/864169/connect-to-two-wifi-networks-with-one-wifi-network-card-on-linux) by agtoever