# More than 2 routers with same SSID

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

I would like to configure 3 or 4 routers in a way that they all have the same SSID.

I saw this very helpful question + answers:

[How can I get the same SSID for multiple access points?](https://superuser.com/questions/122441/how-can-i-get-the-same-ssid-for-multiple-access-points),

and also this explicit help with configuration:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ConfiguringTwoWirelessRoutersWithOneSSIDNetworkNameAtHomeForFreeRoaming.aspx

but unfortunately I think it only deals with the setup of just two routers with the same SSID. My question is,  how would one properly extent that idea to configure for instance 3 or 4 routers with the same SSID? I know that the principle of the configuration will work for more than 2 routers, but I don't know how to explicitly do it. For instance I wouldn't know which IP addresses to give to the routers. (?)

This is the first time I ask a question on this website, so please let me know if there is anything wrong with my question/formulation/anything!

Comment: The directions that work for 2 routers will work for any number of routers

Comment: Thank you @Ramhound for your comment. But what is still unclear to me, is which IP's you give for all routers? just .2, .3 etc? thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question to add this info.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get the same SSID for multiple access points?](http://superuser.com/questions/122441/how-can-i-get-the-same-ssid-for-multiple-access-points)

Comment: @Xavierjazz, I will straight away. @'TECHIE007, I already saw that question, please read in my question why I think this is not the same! Thanks!

Comment: You may not think it's the same, but I do. Hence the vote. ;) As your question currently stands, all the answers you requested are in the answer(s) on the linked dupe. You've also accepted an answer that doesn't answer your specifics you've edited in, and just points back to the same (duplicate) question.  Anyhow, takes more than just my vote. ;)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation 'TECHIE007. It's true that I accepted an answer that doesn't answer the specifics that I've added in, but that is because now I see that the specifics I asked about are apparently not important. If you'd like I can remove the question in total?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll explain this very briefly. You should set up one router as your "main" router. Then set up the other routers/access points in what you would call bridged mode. You should also consider using separate channels to avoid interference.

```
Example:
Router 1 - Channel 1
Bridge 2 - Channel 3
Bridge 3 - Channel 6
Brdige 4 - Channel 9
```

Check here for a more in-depth read:
[How can I get the same SSID for multiple access points?](https://superuser.com/questions/122441/how-can-i-get-the-same-ssid-for-multiple-access-points)

Comment: If you can't configure your secondary routers in "bridge mode" then you simply disable DHCP on the secondary router in question and give it a static IP (via it's web GUI) that must be within your subnet range but not within your DHCP pool/scope. Plan your network! Plan your DHCP pool. Plan your static IPs. Plan your reservations. Get a piece of paper and draw a box for your main modem/router (the one that provides Internet to your network). Find out if your secondary routers have a "bridge" or "access point" mode - if not then you'll need to give them static IPs and disable DHCP on them.

Comment: I thank you both very much. I guess I was wrong thinking that going from 2 to 3 routers would cause additional complications.

Comment: Also I'm sorry I tried to upvote but apparently I don't have enough reputation yet!

Comment: :). It seems that this answer does answer your question. If so, please  mark it as accepted so the answerer can reap the points.