# Which WiFi channel and Channel Width can support more distance?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-access-point, wifi-configuration

I am far away from the modem router and have a very weak signal. There is no other wifi signal, so could you please tell me which Channel Width (20mhz or 40mhz) and channel (2.412ghz or 2.484ghz) is better?

I know these settings are not so important and there is some physical way to increase it, but I just want increase a much as possible!

Comment: buy a wifi range extender as [in](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=wifi+range+extender)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Waves attenuate more quickly at higher frequencies, so 2.412ghz is better. That said, you, being human, won't see any difference between the two. It would take a sensitive piece of equipment to measure any effective difference between the two even in a clean environment.

On channel width. More width = greater throughput. It has no impact whatsoever on range.

You'll need a WiFi extender.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Alex Atkinson that you probably need an extender - or either move your accesspoint or get a second one ( see [How can I get the same SSID for multiple access points?](https://superuser.com/questions/122441/how-can-i-get-the-same-ssid-for-multiple-access-points) )

To answer your question you will probably see increased range on 20 MHz compared to 40 Mhz - specifically a 3 dB stronger signal. This is because going from 20 to 40 Mhz means spreading your output-power into a larger frequency band - You maintain the same output-power but you basically maintain two seperate wifi-channels. This means dividing your power between two frequency bands, half for each, which is consistent with a 3 dB decrease.