# Wifi Extender/Multiple Routers on 1 Network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I live with a bunch of people in a pretty big building. We've always had terrible WiFi and we're trying to improve it. Basically, we'll upgrade our routers (just upgraded bandwidth).

We have several Ethernet ports throughout the building. If we hook up multiple routers to different Ethernet ports, is there a way to make them appear as a single network (and have WiFi devices pick the strongest nearby signal)?

If so, are there any companies that make turnkey solutions for this type of thing?

I've seen some stuff about tomato and while we could just get some WiFi extenders, it seems like our WiFi would be faster if we had multiple independent connections to the internet.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/122441/how-can-i-get-the-same-ssid-for-multiple-access-points

Comment: One router period.  From there you can use multiple access points or AP's plugged into the Ethernet ports (provided that those ports are connected to the single router).  Note that most routers can also be used in AP mode, but make sure they are configured with DHCP and such turned off)

Comment: Looking for that? http://superuser.com/questions/122441/how-can-i-get-the-same-ssid-for-multiple-access-points

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a single router, and there multiple access points throughout the building. If multiple APs have the same SSID and password for then devices will automatically switch between them.