# Multiple access points with the same details

Tags: wifi-configuration

I'm looking to extend my wifi so that it extends all the way from my home, across the garden, and to the garage.

If I installed an access point in the garage with the same name and password, would that look like the same ap to connected devices?

If not, what could I do to ensure coverage across the 3 areas?

Comment: Is your access point hard-wired to the same network? If not, then no it will not work the same. I think you are looking for a wireless repeater, or you would want to add an outdoor wireless access point (or one with an external antenna) that can be hardwired to the same network.

Comment: Both would be hard wired to the same network.

Comment: oh, then it should work just fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the same SSID for multiple access points?](http://superuser.com/questions/122441/how-can-i-get-the-same-ssid-for-multiple-access-points)

Answer (score 0):

If you set an access point with the same SSID and the same password, your devices will attempt to connect to the one with the strongest signal. However, for this to work you may also want your two access points to have the same BSSID, the same mac address. In this way, there would be no way for your device to make the difference between the two APs.

Comment: Is this something that can be done easily?

Comment: It depends of your router. If you use for instance a Raspberry PI as a router, yes it's easy, you just have to change the wireless card mac address. For proprietary routers, the mac address is most of the time not changeable. However, this may not be necessary if you have the same SSID and the same password. You will maybe have to retype the password one time for each APs.