# Bridge Network Failure

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, bridge

Quite some time ago, I decided to extend the signals of my WiFi set up to the rest of the house. To do so, I used an old Wifi I had lying around and connected the two with an ethernet cable which is about 40 to 50 meters long. I set up the second router to bridge mode and let it set itself up.

Now after a couple of months, I am a little frustrated that my internet connection keeps on dropping and I usually have to restart my bridged WiFi to get the internet to work again.

I have almost no experience in network management, what I suspect is some sort of conflict in my second WiFi. I have listed the things I have tried towards the end.

Here is my setup:

> Main Router (ISP branded):
>
> IP 192.168.1.1
>
> ConnectionType: DHCP

Secondary Router (Tenda N11)

> IP 192.168.2.1
>
> Connection Type: DHCP
>
> Gateway: 192.168.1.1
>
> DNS Server: 192.168.1.1
>
> Bridged.

Now when connected to the main router, we usually don't face any problems and get promised speeds of up to 50Mbps. However, On the secondary router, we do get speeds of between 40 and 50Mbps but after a certain amount of time connections drop completely, we usually require a manual restart of the router.

Looking around the internet, I came across various articles about how to bridge the network.

- One recommended I change the IP of the second router to something similar to 192.168.1.15 however this created a conflict and the router changed the IP automatically.
- Other articles recommended that I install DD-WRT however this is not available for my router.
- Other things I have tried are to change the Wireless channel but that has not helped either.

As I mentioned earlier, I do not have a lot of experience in network related things, so if there is any additional information I need to provide, you can ask in the comments and I will update the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I glanced at a Tenda N11 manual online, and the only time they refer to "Network Bridge" is in reference to WDS, which is a situation where you don't have an Ethernet cable between your two Wi-Fi APs, so you have to make a wireless connection between them. That is not your situation, so you should have your N11's wireless in AP mode.

Make sure your Ethernet cable from the upstream Wi-Fi AP plugs into a yellow LAN port on your N11. Make sure your N11's DHCP Server feature is disabled. Make sure your N11's LAN-side IP address is in the 192.168.1.x range so you can still reach its web admin interface.

Comment: This actually seems to have worked pretty well! However, I do have one question. Can both my wireless have the same SSID? While changing the settings I had changed the SSID of my second router to better recognize it.

Comment: @UzairHayat Yes, if you give them both the same SSID, make sure you give them both exactly the same security settings. I recommend pure WPA2-PSK (AES-CCMP only, no WPA/TKIP) and a strong passphrase. Also note that you should put them on *different*, non-overlapping channels. For more information, see here: http://superuser.com/questions/122441/how-can-i-get-the-same-ssid-for-multiple-access-points/122508#122508

Comment: thank you so much! Just made the changes. Hope this works.