# Duplicate WiFi in another room, using only an Ethernet connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wifi-configuration

I have an ordinary ADSL router, which also acts as WiFi AP. This router is connected to an Ethernet network, which includes several devices in several rooms. The WiFi signal can not reach all these rooms and I would like to avoid a simple WiFi range extender.

I am looking for a device which can be connected through Ethernet, far from the router, which can emulate the same WiFi network of the router. It should basically act as an additional antenna. This device should make a WiFi connection available in its area, using its Ethernet connection to the router for the actual data flow.

Does it exist? How is it called?

Comment: Yes it exists, it is called a WiFi AP, or Access Point. I find it funny that you actually use the correct terminology in your post...

Comment: Please also read this interesting similar [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/122441/how-can-i-get-the-same-ssid-for-multiple-access-points).

Comment: @leopal keep in mind, that question and answer is dated 2010. A lot has changed since, especially in the mobile department where a longer battery life is wishful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is actually called an AP, or Access Point.

Your Router has WiFi support but an Access Point is a smaller device that usually has only one LAN port and one or more Antenna's with a configuration for accessing that specific AP.

You can specify the same SSID and password as the rest of the WiFi network, but keep in mind that devices will not automatically switch networks unless they are out of range of the network they were in. This will mean that it is possible to stay connected to a network that is almost out of range, giving slow speeds.

There is also the ability to use a mesh network and a range extender. In this situation, all AP's talk to eachother and they will carry the connection to another closer AP. The biggest downside to this, is that it usually means you need to replace your entire WIFI setup to accomodate this and the speeds will be slower as bandwidth is reserved for communication between the wifi points.

Comment: I do not totally agree with the second paragraph. Assuming that an AP has exactly the same SSID and security configuration it depends on client's roaming algorithms and thresholds if the client will switch network once a better AP is detected. I agree that there are clients which not perform well on this **but** this is not the case.

Comment: @leopal Most clients will not switch until out of range. This is the standard for quite a while now to safe battery power. There are exceptions, but they are too few to rely on, which I felt could make the answer far more complicated if I stated such.

Comment: Thank you so much. In my case, positions of router and this hypothetical AP are such that there would be no overlapping zones between their signals. Therefore, the problem you mentioned would not arise.